# How to customise the Cognito OIDC Sign-In prompt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK to setup a Cognito UserPool to sign in to my app with Github via an OIDC IdProvider.

I have it working and can sign in using my Github account, but the sign-in prompt looks like this:
[image: Cognito github sign in prompt]

The CDK code for declaring the UserPool IdProvider is [here](https://github.com/shorn/zinc/blob/d82bfb12de34b59e88f4f98506bc32cf65f8f08f/aws-infra/src/Stack/CognitoGithubStackV1.ts#L59).

How can I customise this prompt?

Initially, I'd like to change the words to something like "Sign in with Github", and ultimately I'd probably want to add some more context to that for the user (what I'm doing with the data, etc.)

I can work around it a little by customising the name of the IdProvider from `zinc-github-oidc` to `Github` or something, but I'd like to control more than just the button text (plus I prefer to keep the IdProvider name more technically-oriented since it's used in data fields inside Cognito and token claims etc.)